# Disable dropdown list in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I have filled up dropdown as:
Controller:

```
var db = new TransFormezEntities()           
ViewBag.fldCountry_ID = new SelectList(db.tblCountries, "fldCountry_ID", 
                                    "fldCountryName", stateDetails.fldCountry_ID)
```

View

Country

```
<div class="display-field" id = "fldCountry_ID">
      @Html.DropDownList("fldCountry_ID", "[Select]")
</div>
```

I want to make it readonly or disable how can i please ?

Answer (score 0):

try following code snippets

**For disabled**

```
  Html.DropDownList("fldCountry_ID", ViewBag.fldCountry_ID ,
                                       new { @disabled = "disabled" })
```

**For readonly**

```
Html.DropDownList("fldCountry_ID", ViewBag.fldCountry_ID , 
                                  new { @readonly = "true" })
```